# The exception is not caught in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, try-catch, httprequest, unhandled-exception

In my application I got an exception message. This occurs when I throw false when an if() condition fails. The error message I got is as below

```
Unhandled exception at 0x74fe812f in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: bool at memory location 0x0015c87b..
```

My code that generates this error is

```
if((dwStatus!= 302) && (dwStatus< 200 || dwStatus> 299))
    throw false;
```

Here dwStatus is a `DWORD` which got from `pHttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatus)` where `pHttpFile` is an object reference of `CHttpFile`

The codes are in a `try` block and appropriate `catch` blocks are also there.

How this error occurs.

**EDIT**

This is the catch block

```
catch(CException* pErr)
{
    TCHAR szErr[1024];
    pErr->GetErrorMessage(szErr,1024);
    pErr->Delete();
    bRet = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: can you show the catch block?

Comment: Your `catch` block catches objects of type `CException*`.  You are throwing a `bool`.  Why do you expect this catch block to handle that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your catch block is catching a `CException*` type of exception, but you are throwing a `bool` type of exception. If you want to catch that exception, you'll need a catch block that catches exceptions of type `bool`:

```
catch(bool exception)
{
  //report the exception, or recover, or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by your throw. That's what throw is supposed to do. If your question is about why the exception is not caught, then please edit your question and post your catch code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Question is updated and catch block is added.